# React+Jest in vsCode: How to debug deeper in integration tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to debug the behavior of a click in a button.
I'm able to debug in the test and simulate the click, but the breakpoint in the onClick function is never activated.

The Component:

```
class ButtonA extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      qtyClicks: 0
    };
  }

  onClick() {
   // ****************** Here I added the unreachable breakpoint
    const { qtyClicks } = this.state;     
    this.setState({ qtyClicks: qtyClicks + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='experiment'>
       <button onClick={this.onClick} className='my-button'>+</button>
        <span>{this.state.qtyClicks}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The test in jest:

```
  const wrapper = mount(
       <Provider...>... 
          <ButtonA/>
  </Provider>);

  it('test click button', () => {

    const myButton = wrapper.find('.my-button');
    //*********** Here I'm able to debug easily.
    myButton.simulate('click');
  });
```

Any ideas of how debug code inside of ButtonA?

Comment: Does the `onClick` function get called? Put a `console.log()` in there and check that.

Comment: found this resource see if it helps: https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/08/24/How-to-debug-jest-tests/